# Can a crack in a sink be fixed?

Tags: sink, porcelain

Putting apartment up for rent.

Just want to fix this hairline crack without replacing the whole sink.  It's about 1/16" deep (can just feel it with the tip of your fingernail)

Is it possible? How?

[image: up]

[image: bottom]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You might have been happy living with it, but it's a probable red-flag issue.

Acceptable fix - replace sink. If you have a "Habitat for Humanity ReStore" nearby (or some other "thrift store that deals in fixtures") it might not even be that expensive. Doesn't need to be a fancy overpriced brand but it needs to be intact.

Slumlord fix - epoxy or leave as is. It will never be "right" short of replacement. It will lose you renters with reasonable expectations, as they will smell slumlord when they see that sink at the apartment showing and keep looking - elsewhere.

Comment: I agree ... and it's not a hairline crack. He will loose renters.+1

Comment: As a landlord myself, and a former renter of many years, I see two key points to consider. Renters can be picky, and if you get one that is not, my next point might sell you: As a landlord, I know tenants do not "have to" care (they think "it's not mine"), so since it is cracked, it is only a matter of time that any repair will lend itself to failure, and water will leak, and support structure will get wet, and many many more costly repairs are in your future.